# Spyder not opening after pip install into evironment

Tags: pip, conda, spyder

Win 10 x64, Python 3.10.8, Spyder 5.4.3, spyder-kernels 2.4.3

Steps taken:

- created a virtual conda environment & activated it
- `pip install spyder-kernels`
- `pip install spyder`
- `spyder`

Result  - nothing it just returns a new command line & no Spyder.

Its listed when I `conda list`

What's happening here?

Comment: Since you're using conda environments, is there a specific reason that you're trying to use `pip`, rather than `conda install spyder` ?

Comment: @nekomatic I keep all packages in a given environment as either all `pip` or all `conda`. Also, I've had a number of nighmares with the `conda` install clashing with packages so I now generally only install using `pip` at the moment.